# Why entity values are stored in different tables based on attribute type?

Tags: database, eav

The values of customer entities stored in different tables based on the attribute type

ex:

```
customer_entity
customer_entity_datetime
customer_entity_decimal
customer_entity_int
customer_entity_text
customer_entity_varchar
```

can you explain the benefit/need to store the entity values like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the based on EAV structure. Any attribute is stored on the basis of attribute type so that they can add as much column as they want. And its easy to use any where, like search.

The main reason to use many table is to reduce the space of database. If we use single table then we have to maintain text type in DB and it will wastage of memory for small data. That's why they created different table according to data type.

Also You don't need to change the product table definition for each attribute that you create

Comment: I'd say, the main reason for EAV is flexibility: You don't need to change the product table definition for each attribute that you create.

Comment: @fschmengler even we can store all the values of attribute in one table like customer_entity_values, why many tables based on attribute type?

Comment: @manokarthickkarthick The "value" column must have a type and you don't want to store everything in binary format.

Comment: @fschmengler if we store all as text in a single table , what are the drawbacks?

Comment: only memory or anything else?

Comment: memory and no support of type specific mysql operations (for ex. date comparison)

Comment: Also its good for search. If you store date in text or varchar type then its not easy to search.